# Find encryption method, Decrypt Non-Cyrillic/Non readable characters

Tags: decryption, encryption

I have an old file, I know what it contains, I know that this is encoding without a password, any privatekey and secretkey. This is some kind of encoded file/string, possibly converted several times.

[Here's the encoded stroke - t‰„ЌЉ‚Ћ†™ќ‰ ›ќ–Ўљ§®°®¬·®»»·БАГЗЗАМНЛУТХЩЩТЬРуБЙРЪРдслТЫ](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex(%27Auto%27)&input=MHg3NCwgMHg4OSwgMHg4NCwgMHg4RCwgMHg4QSwgMHg4MiwgMHg4RSwgMHg4NiwgMHg5OSwgMHg5OCwgMHg5RCwgMHg4OSwgMHhBMCwgMHg5QiwgMHg5RCwgMHg5NiwgMHhBMSwgMHg5QSwgMHhBNywgMHhBRSwgMHhCMCwgMHhBRSwgMHhBQywgMHhCNywgMHhBRSwgMHhCQiwgMHhCQiwgMHhCNywgMHhDMSwgMHhDMCwgMHhDMywgMHhDNywgMHhDNywgMHhDMCwgMHhDQywgMHhDRCwgMHhDQiwgMHhEMywgMHhEMiwgMHhENSwgMHhEOSwgMHhEOSwgMHhEMiwgMHhEQywgMHhEMCwgMHhGMywgMHhDMSwgMHhDOSwgMHhEMCwgMHhEQSwgMHhEMCwgMHhFNCwgMHhGMSwgMHhFQiwgMHhEMiwgMHhEQg)

And perhaps there are two different encodings broken into parts.

First part - t‰„ЌЉ‚Ћ†™ќ‰ ›ќ–Ўљ§®°®¬·®»»·

[Second part - БАГЗЗАМНЛУТХЩЩТЬРуБЙРЪРдслТЫ](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex(%27Auto%27)&input=MHhDMSwgMHhDMCwgMHhDMywgMHhDNywgMHhDNywgMHhDMCwgMHhDQywgMHhDRCwgMHhDQiwgMHhEMywgMHhEMiwgMHhENSwgMHhEOSwgMHhEOSwgMHhEMiwgMHhEQywgMHhEMCwgMHhGMywgMHhDMSwgMHhDOSwgMHhEMCwgMHhEQSwgMHhEMCwgMHhFNCwgMHhGMSwgMHhFQiwgMHhEMiwgMHhEQg)

Here's what might be contained here - LS80 095116A8A881F030A7A7292E 22042022 05:34:09:52:C9:86

Please help me find an encryption method, I will be very grateful. I apologize right away if this is written stupidly, I'm weak in cryptography

UPD : I found a program that processed this file. Here are the possible functions from IDA

[image]

Comment: Hi, it's not clear what the question is and you are making a lot of assumptions by pasting stuff via your browser and expecting anyone to be able to help you from that. At a minimum you'd have to provide a hexdump or the Base32 (or similarly) encoded form of the data. By pasting some Cyrillic letters, you seem to have already assumed a certain encoding and removed the ability of all readers to look at raw data. Please update your question. Also, have you tried [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/)?

Comment: 0x74, 0x89, 0x84, 0x8D, 0x8A, 0x82, 0x8E, 0x86, 0x99, 0x98, 0x9D, 0x89, 0xA0, 0x9B, 0x9D, 0x96, 
0xA1, 0x9A, 0xA7, 0xAE, 0xB0, 0xAE, 0xAC, 0xB7, 0xAE, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xB7, 0xC1, 0xC0, 0xC3, 0xC7, 
0xC7, 0xC0, 0xCC, 0xCD, 0xCB, 0xD3, 0xD2, 0xD5, 0xD9, 0xD9, 0xD2, 0xDC, 0xD0, 0xF3, 0xC1, 0xC9, 
0xD0, 0xDA, 0xD0, 0xE4, 0xF1, 0xEB, 0xD2, 0xDB - Here is hex. Yeah, i tried 2cyr, most popular decoders

Comment: How do you know there's no password/key, and what makes you think `LS80 ...` might be the encoded data? Where's the file from? _Any_ context would be helpful...

Comment: @user7290573 I know what is in the file because I saw the source code of the application, what it contains in its key. There is no password or key, I talked with a person on the forum who extended this key for me. He doesn’t want to talk about the decryption method, he said it’s easy and you should try it yourself

Comment: @user7290573 i can share a file via dropbox or something like that

Comment: also i pinned screenshot from IDA

Comment: Uploading the file and the program/binary would indeed be very helpful.

Comment: While you edited your question, you didn't include the raw (hex) form there. So now I did (via link to CyberChef). But without providing more information it's unlikely anyone will be able to help. At least we have the raw form now.